# Why are the letters appended instead of the word?

Tags: python, json, loops, append

I am currently dealing with a JSON file from the DSTC8 schema dialogue: https://github.com/google-research-datasets/dstc8-schema-guided-dialogue

I am trying to extract the value for key 'act' for each dialogue and my code is as shown below :

```
with open('path/dialogues_001.json', 'r') as f:
data = json.load(f)

    col = []
    #Looping through each dialogue
    for i in data:
        row = []
        x.append(q)
         #For every turns, we will loop through the 'frames' and 'actions'
         for j in i['turns']:
             for k in j['frames']:
                 for l in k['actions']:
                    #Looping through the key ; 'act'
                    for m in l['act']:
                        q.append(m)

print(x[0])
```

The append works however the results is written as

```
['I', 'N', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'M', 'I', 'N', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'M', 'I', 'N', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'M', '_', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'R', 'E', 'Q', 'U', 'E', 'S', 'T']
```

instead of `['INFORM', 'INFORM, INFORM_INTENT, 'REQUEST']`

do you guys know what goes wrong in my code where letters are appended instead of the word value ?

Comment: `for m in l['act']` is looping through every letter in `l['act']`. Remove that, and just have `q.append(l['act'])`. I think you'd find it more helpful to see what was going on if you added comments for what the data was at each step, and the variable names described what the thing was.

Comment: Thank you for the tips and advise! I will add the comments for sure

Comment: Yes, _please_ use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Wow - that's a lot of nesting!

Comment: @costaparas let me know if you have another easy way to parse the JSON file without too many for loops :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the last `for` loop as it is iterating over the letters of the value found for key `act`.

Also, if you use meaningful object names that will help you in maintaining the code much better:

```
import json

acts = []
with open('inp.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for dialogue in data:
        for turn in dialogue.get('turns', []):
            for frame in turn.get('frames', []):
                for action in frame.get('actions', {}):
                    act = action.get('act')
                    acts.append(act)
print(acts)
```

Subset of Output:

```
['INFORM', 'INFORM_INTENT', 'REQUEST', 'REQUEST', 'INFORM']
```

Note: You may want to use `set()` datatype if you only want the unique act names.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can turn `json` to `dataframe` and find all acts with regex by the dialog id.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_json('path/dialogues_001.json')
df.turns = df.turns.apply(str)
df['acts'] = [re.findall(r"'act': '(\w+)'", row) for row in df['turns']]
```

Now you have all dialog ids with their act names. It works also because according to the Scheme Representation in [DSTC8](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/dstc8-schema-guided-dialogue), `acts` only appear under `actions`.  [image: Output example]